# Convert query result to JSON

Tags: python, json, postgresql, flask

I have my python function that returns a query result:

```
class Arc_Nodes_Data(Resource):
  def get(self):
        #Connect to databse
        conn = connectDB()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        #Perform query and return JSON data
        try:
          cur.execute("SELECT start_location FROM trips UNION SELECT end_location FROM trips")
        except:
          print("Error executing select")
        NodeList = list (i[0] for i in cur.fetchall())
        return jsonify ({'id':NodeList})
```

This function returns the results in the following format:

```
{
  "id": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
}
```

I tried this function above so that the output could be like this:

```
[{ 
  "id": "a"
  }, {
  "id": "b"
  }, {
  "id": "c"
}]
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. I can't seem to manipulate Python dictionaries very well so maybe that's the problem. How can I get the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to do that what you want:

```
return jsonify ([{'id': x} for x in Nodelist])
```

That comprehension make 3 dictionaries wiht each containing one id element.

You can also combine last to lines in one line:

```
return jsonify ([{'id': i[0]} for i in cur.fetchall()])
```

Comment: it gives this error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` for both of your answers

Comment: I can't reproduce your code but if `Nodelist` contains list with `["a", "b", "c"]`, then the following code returns list that you want. Which function does trow that error? Maybe `jsonify` wants to have something else as a argument.

Comment: I think it has to do with `kwarg`because when I use `json.dumps([{'id': i[0]} for i in cur.fetchall()])`it works